# How to determine which one is fast Big Oh Notation

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

I am working on a given question below and trying to give my answer in chart where I compare both A and B steps, however is there any other way ?
Suppose that algorithm A takes 1000n^3 steps and algorithm B takes 2^n steps (Note the carot symbol ^ means raise to the power) for a problem of size n. For what size of problem is algorithm A faster than B (meaning algorithm A has fewer steps than B)?

Comment: I assume A will become O(n) constant and B exponential O(x^n)  ...

Comment: No it becomes O(n^3) vs O(x^n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is 24 and you can find it by writing a program like the one follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i=1; i<100; i++){
            double b = pow(2, i);
            double a = 1000 * pow(i, 3);
            if (b> a){
                System.out.println(" i is " + i + " as a result a is " + a + " and b is " + b);
                break;
            }
        }
```

And here is the output  :
 i is 24 as a result a is 1.3824E7 and b is 1.6777216E7

Comment: If you want to compare two O notations what happens in these cases is that we compare them for big cases so 2^n for big cases is always bigger than n^3 and you do not need a calculation for that. But your question is not that. Your question asks specifically at what point a becomes more efficient than b

Comment: It is math. Check this out and use this as a cheat sheet     http://bigocheatsheet.com/img/big-o-complexity.png

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use O-notation:
`1000*n^3 = O(n^3)`, `2^n = O(2^n)`, so theoretically O(n^3) is much much smaller than (2^n).

But if you want to use precise expression, then it becomes a pure math problem: any math software which can plot function could show you when and which function is greater.

The reason we use O-notation is to ignore the constants. This is not because big hidden constant can really be ignored, but because the estimate of the constant is typically not accurate - it depends a lot on details of your hardware and program.